# Crystal Reports Formula Logic

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 and cannot figure out the proper expression for suppressing fields.

In this case, say I have a pill diary.

```
{PILL.TYPE_ANTI_INFLAMMATORY}
{PILL.TYPE_PAIN_REDUCTION}
{@INTEGER_TYPE1}
{@INTEGER_TYPE2}
```

The first two elements from the data tables PILL are columns of pill types.  The first one is a column of type of anti-inflammatory pills, the second pain reduction.  These columns each contain unique information.

In the second two elements, is a column of integers either negative or positive.  These are formula columns (date difference between two dates.)

My expression:

```
{PILL.TYPE_ANTI_INFLAMMATORY} = "Advil" or
{PILL.TYPE_PAIN_REDUCTION} in ["Tylenol", "Acetometaphin"] and
{@INTEGER_TYPE1} > 1 or
{@INTEGER_TYPE2} > 1
```

What I am trying to do is display any row in which ANTI_INFLAMMATORY is equal to Advil or PAIN_REDUCTION is equal to Tylenol or Acetometaphin **while also** one of the columns of integer type is greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you!! You just taught a man to fish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
{PILL.TYPE_ANTI_INFLAMMATORY}="Advil" or
{PILL.TYPE_PAIN_REDUCTION} IN ["Tylenol","Acetometaphin"]
) and
(
{@INTEGER_TYPE1} > 1 or 
{@INTEGER_TYPE2} > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF ({PILL.TYPE_ANTI_INFLAMMATORY}="Advil" or {PILL.TYPE_PAIN_REDUCTION} IN ["Tylenol","Acetometaphin"]) 
AND
({@INTEGER_TYPE1} > 1 or {@INTEGER_TYPE2} > 1) THEN
FALSE ELSE TRUE
```